# Can a candidate transfer their delegates to another?

Tags: united-states, primaries, democratic-primary

In 2020 US democratic primary election, can a candidate transfer their delegates to another,

- either when they drop out
- or when they reach the convention?

Several tweets suggest that might happen in the second scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite a duplicate, because the Republicans and Democrats _could_ have different rules on the matter.  That said, neither question specifies party, and I don't think there's currently any differences on this, so it could be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

When presidential candidates drop out, they aren't necessarily removed from the ballot. Their name will still appear on some state primaries and will still collect delegates. Consequently, there are procedures for when candidates no longer contesting the nomination still have delegates. In most cases, **delegates arrive at the convention uncommitted**, or are required by their state to vote for their pledged candidate in only the first round of voting. Technically these abandoned delegates can vote however they want (when not bound by state law) if their candidate has dropped out. Obviously, the candidate they were pledged too still holds a large amount influence over them. Ergo, a candidate can't directly transfer delegates,but they can endorse the nominee of their choice and then their previous delegates will have direction for how to vote at the convention.